# What is the simplest way in SQL to determine a ratio(1:1) from a generated result?

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL and from what I've been told the solution to my query is a simple line or two of code.  Basically, I have a database of individual profiles that includes name, favorite book, political leanings and others.  I was provided with a code cell that determines percentages and lift - see below:

[image: code]

and result:

[image: result]

Basically I just want to narrow the results down to instances where the perc_con and perc_libs are within a range of .8-1.2:.8-1.2 i.e 1:1.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include code and example data as text, not as images.

Comment: Have you tried using something like `where perc_con > 0.8 and perc_con < 1.2`, and so on?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes I tried and it didn't allow me to - let me try to edit and try again.  That was exactly my initial guess but I kept getting an error - maybe i'm just not placing it on the right line?

Answer (score 0):

Your perc_con  is a calculated field which is ( BC.C/C.NC). So your where will be

```
where BC.C > 5 
and BL.L > 5
and ( BC.C/C.NC) > 0.8 
and ( BC.C/C.NC) < 1.2 
and ( BL.L/L.NL) > 0.8
and ( BL.L/L.NL) < 1.2
```